# Azure Web App Diagnostics logging does not honour log filters

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I've configured logging in my application like so:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            ...
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();

            if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                logging.AddConsole();
            }
            else
            {
                logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            }

            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);

            logging.AddFilter((category, level) =>
            {
                if (category.Contains("Microsoft") && level > LogLevel.Information)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        })
        .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
            serviceCollection.Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.BlobName = $"auditLog-{DateTime.Today:dd-MM-yy}.txt";
            })
        );
```

However, I'm facing two problems:

- I can't get any logs to display in my Application Output locally (VS for Mac)
- The logs in Azure Blob Storage still contain all of the **Information** level Microsoft and System logs, and do not appear to be respecting the log filters I've applied

How can I configure logging to Azure Blob to only include logs generated by my application, rather than all of the Microsoft and System **Information** level logs?

Comment: did you enable logging on web app?

Comment: Yes, it's logging to blob storage just fine - but the logs contain all of the Information level Microsoft logs.